# Can ESXi pass video card to VM to do CUDA?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, cuda

I have an ESXi 4.1 running on hardware that can run 4 16-lane PCI-e cards.  I would like to have access to the underlying hardware from a Linux VM, to run some CUDA programs.

So far all I can see from inside of Linux VM is the generic VMware video card.  I installed VMware tools, and `lspci` still gives me the same `VGA compatible controller: VMware SVGA II Adapter.`

Is it at all possible to access CUDA devices from a VM guest?

Comment: What does the manual say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your system is fully AMD-Vi or VT-d compliant then you should be able to go into the host's advance settings and 'pass through' the device/s to a given VM. This isn't certain to work or be stable but does work for quite a lot of kit, though it stops things like vMotion/FT/HA working properly if that matters to you. I'd say give it a go but if it doesn't work, well it doesn't work ok.

edit - here's grab of where to look;

[image]

So it's host/Configuration, Advanced Settings then choose 'Configure Passthrough' - you're on your own from there though as I haven't done this with a GPU.

Comment: BIOS is updated, all the VT-x/VT-d are enabled.  How do you pass-through a video card in ESXi?  I thought that's what vmware-tools do.

Comment: Like I said it's under the advanced settings for the host when using the VSClient. I'll try to post some images on Monday.

Comment: I configured the video cards to do passthrough, however I still do not see them inside of the VM, or cannot add them to the VM in VM guest settings as a video card or as a PCI device (they're grayed out).  Are there any other tricks I should be aware of?

Comment: No, sorry, there's very limited support for this function to be honest, pretty much just NICs really, sorry dude, at least your tried.

Answer (score 1):

We are running several ESXi servers at university. I was not able to pass through a GPU to a VM (Windows, Linux) to run a CUDA program. If you want to share / use a GPU in one or many VMs, please have a look at NVIDIA Grid. For more information please review:

- [NVIDIA blog entry - How VMware and NVIDIA Are Bringing GPU Sharing to the Masses](http://blogs.nvidia.com/blog/2015/02/03/vmware-nvidia-gpu-sharing/)
- [NVIDIA TRUE VIRTUAL ACCELERATION WITH GPUs](http://www.nvidia.com/object/grid-technology.html)

Comment: Still no luck with this?